# Web Connector to CodeIgniter Queue Troubleshooting

Tags: codeigniter, quickbooks

I am using Quickbooks 13 and the standard Web connector.
I am using CodeIgniter and the standard Class provided here:
https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/example_codeigniter_web_connector/controllers/quickbooks.php

Web Connector runs and connects to the queue through the controller function provided above, but not every time.  Web Connector will run multiple times and give the status that there is nothing in the queue and then with nothing changed it will suddenly connect and process.

I have implemented this now two different times with two completely different sites but with the same results.

Is this a standard problem?  Is anyone else having this problem?  What additional information would be helpful for me to provide to help me troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post your code.

Post the Web Connector log file.

Check your PHP error log for errors.

Without taking those steps, there's no way to troubleshoot this.

Comment: The code I am using is an exact copy paste from the class I posted above.  No changes.  There are no errors in the Web Connector Log file or the PHP error log.  There are no errors being thrown at all.  The web connector simply says there is no work for it to process while there are items in the queue.  And then suddenly with no change to the queue or the code it processes everything perfectly.  Usually after about a 10-20 minute wait.  Any other thoughts on where I could go to find issues?

Comment: Are you positive you've used all of the latest code from GitHub?

Comment: You'll still need to post your logs. No one will be able to tell you anything without at least seeing the Web Connector log file.

Comment: The problem with the logs is that I am in the middle of implementation so there are quiet a few errors in the logs due to other issues that I have already resolved.  I could wipe those out but then I'll just be posting blank documents.  I've run down the errors on the adjustments I have made.  But the delay I have posted about is happening on basic initial installation of the code straight out of GitHub. I'm wondering if it is the way I have implemented things which is why I was hoping this is an error someone else has encountered.

Comment: Then clear the logs, wait for it to happen again, and post the new logs. Are you POSITIVE you're using all of the very latest code from GitHub?

Comment: Nope.  I'll try that again first.  If that doesn't work I'll dump the logs and run it again and post those.

Comment: So I went back through the latest code and found this line: "'deny_reallyfast_logins' => false, " It was not in my code and going back through the database logs (which I should have posted but didn't think about) I found that a "reallyfast login denied" error was coming up regularly.  So you were right.  I needed to post my logs and the latest version of the code.  Thank you for your help!